# Как у input добавлять/удалять атрибуты в зависимости от выбора?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма:

```
<form>
   <div id='type'>
      <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
      <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
      <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' /> 
   </div>
</form>
```

Как в jQuery или JavaScript сделать так, чтобы при клике на радио кнопку в `<input>` устанавливался атрибут `"checked="checked"`? Тогда как у остальных до этого выбранных этот атрибут должен пропадать. Т.е. у выбранной кнопки всегда должен присутствувать `"checked="checked"`.

Например, мы выбрали кнопку с `id='radio1'`, у нее должен появиться атрибут `checked`. После этого мы решили выбрать другую кнопку с `id='radio2'`. После клика на `radio2` у нее появляется атрибут `ckecked`, а у `id='radio1'` этот атрибут пропадает. И так далее для всех радио переключаталей.

Comment: он же и так устанавливается описанным образом, если у них одинаковый аттрибут name указан средствами css

Comment: @lexxl Нужно железно установить в input, чтобы было видно через консоль

Comment: через консоль будет видно. проверить можно так `<input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' checked />` || `$('#radio_1').prop('checked')`

Comment: @lexxl Могли бы написать пример в ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанный функционал реализуется нативными средствами CSS через указание одинакового атрибута `name` для желаемых radio-кнопок.

Если есть необходимость реализовать аналогичное поведение для checkbox-элементов (или всё-таки надо дополнительно жестко задать через `jQuery`), то поможет следующий код:

```js
$(function(){

  $('input').click(function(){
      $('input').each(function(){
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <div id='type'>
      <input type='checkbox' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
      <input type='checkbox' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
      <input type='checkbox' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' /> 
   </div>
</form>
```

Проверить наличие свойства `checked` можно таким образом:

```
$('#radio_1').prop(‌​'checked')
```

При наличии свойства в консоль выведется `true`, при отсутствии `false`.

Comment: _Проверить наличие атрибута checked можно таким образом:_ - а вот и нет - тут проверяется наличие свойства, атрибут при этом может и отсутствовать

Comment: @lexxl Спасибо за ответ! А в Elements в Chrome не меняется значение у элемента

Comment: @Pavel, а зачем нужно чтобы оно менялось?

Comment: @Grundy Нужно, чтобы получить значение value выбранного в данный момент переключателя. Чтобы потом отправить значение через  Ajax серверу.

Comment: @Pavel, для этого абсолютно не нужно наличие атрибута checked в панеле Elements в Chrome

Comment: @lexxl заменил prop на attr и получилось всё что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: @Pavel, очень зря, для `checked` рекомендовано именно _prop_

Comment: @Grundy а почему зря? Для библиотеки 1.6 и ниже по-моему по-другому никак не сделаешь. Не специалист в jQuery, но, мне кажется, что prop и attr пользуются сходими функциями?

Comment: @Pavel, потому что, иногда это может приводить к неожиданным результатам. Кроме того, про версию библиотеки в вопросе ничего не указано, а так как поведение и функции в зависимости от версии очень сильно меняются, принято считать, что речь идет о последней стабильной на данный момент версии.

Comment: @Grundy согласен, подправил ответ